# Xamarin custom control in a datatemplate created with CreateContent()

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have implemented a custom DataTemplateSelector according to: [GitHub Xamarin Forms](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6052).
This allows for a datatemplate to be selected based on an item, which is received through a data binding. This works fine to select a proper datatemplate and render it. However, I am now at a point where I want to add custom controls to this datatemplate (custom buttons). This works on any other page, but for some reason not in this datatemplate.

The relevant lines in the datatemplate:

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Universal_ONE.Views.Controls"


<controls:IconButton Command="{Binding RobotLocationSave}"
                     Image="{StaticResource BoltBlack}"/>
```

The part the datatemplate is selected and created:

```
var templateToUse = templateSelector.SelectTemplate(item, null);
View view = (View)templateToUse.CreateContent();
view.BindingContext = bindingContext;
```

In the catch block I get the error (after calling CreateContent()):

```
Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 371:26. Type controls:IconButton not found in xmlns clr-namespace:Universal_ONE.Views.Controls
```

The problem has to be with the CreateContent(), since using the control outside of this datatemplate works.

**EDIT 1**
I've created a Minimal Working Example: [GitHub](https://github.com/GertjanBrouwer/Xamarin.Forms-Bug-MWE).
The datatemplate is now hardcoded, so I'm sure that one is selected.
The same parseexception gets thrown.

I am trying to compile Xamarin.Forms myself so I can debug the framework itself. However, compiling is not going smooth; thus might take a bit longer.

**EDIT 2**
A bit more info on the MWE:
The MainPage.xaml has the default Xamarin.Forms app code. Below I've added a custom control, which is simply a frame with a label. The text of this label is set via a bindableproperty (not really relevant). Below this control is the datatemplatecontrol added, which in turn calls the datatemplateselector, which returns the datatemplate. This datatemplate contains the same control as the mainpage. Thus the rendered app should have 2 controls. However, in de datatemplatecontrol you can breakpoint on the catch statement (look for my comment). This is where the parseexception will show, which is caused after calling CreateContent() on the datatemplate.

**EDIT 3**
I've not been clear enough I think. But you **have** to put a breakpoint on line 41 of datatemplatecontroler.cs. Since the content of the datatemplate is set to null if the createcontent() fails, thus fails gracefully. When hitting the breakpoint you can read the parseexception.

**EDIT 4**
I've made an issue and a pull request on the Xamarin repository: [GitHub](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/14465). The problem resides with the XamlParser, which has a small bug where it selects the wrong assembly. Inside the issue I've mentioned a workaround which can be used for now.

Comment: Good - you have one case that works, and one that doesn't. The best starting point for debugging. Show all the relevant code *for the case that works*. You said that's on a different page - show the `xmlns:controls` on that page (so we can see that it is identical), and show the line where `IconButton` is used (so we can see if there is something subtlely different there). Also, are both pages in the same namespace? Just to be sure, show the full declaration at the top of both pages `<...>`. Spans several lines, includes `Class` and `xmlns`.

Comment: 1) Have you verified that `templateToUse` is the `DataTemplate` that you expect it to be? First step I would take is to not use a `Selector`: hardcode a reference to that `DataTemplate`. That is, does `MyDataTemplate.CreateContent();` give that same error? 2) Two possible causes to look for: A) A different `xmlns:controls` on the working page. Make sure there isn't a second `xmlns:controls`, that refers to a different namespace. B) The failing page is unable to resolve `Universal_ONE.Views.Controls` namespace. Both pages are in same project?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Hi Steve, thanks for helping. I've created a Minimal Working Example (see edited post). This has the exact same error while also being very simple. This example also ensures that the correct datatemplate is used.

Comment: @jason - do you have time to look at the github project linked from the question?

Comment: I tried to download your example and run it, but the system is running normally, there is no error and no access to the catch method.

Comment: It will fail silently, you have to put a breakpoint in the catch statement on line 41 of datatemplatecontroler.cs. Then read the Exception message. @WenxuLi

Comment: I added a breakpoint in the catch, but the program did not enter the catch method because there was no exception in the statement in the try. And the main page is displayed normally.

Comment: The mainpage is displayed normally since I let it fail gracefully, by setting the content = null. Please provide a screenshot of your mainpag.e

Answer (score 0):

I try to download your example and run it. When I run to Content = CreateTemplateForItem(ItemTemplate); the program does not report an error, so the program skips the catch method. Here is a screenshot of the runtime:

[image]
[image]

Then I tried to actively throw an exception in the try statement (throw new Exception();) to make the program enter the catch method, Here is a screenshot of the runtime:
[image]

Comment: This is indeed the behaviour that "should" happen. "This should work at all times" should indeed been shown. However, if you look at the mainpage.xaml, you see that there is another control added with the text: "This never works" Which also does not work in your case. You should put the breakpoint on line 42, inside the catch statement, to see the error.